# Conexión .net y entorno host con entirex

Tags: c#, iis, wcf

Estoy tratando de realizar una conexión entre .NET y un entorno host utilizando [entirex](http://techcommunity.softwareag.com/pwiki/-/wiki/Main/Integrating%20.NET%20Assemblies%20Using%20EntireX) de software AG.
Si realizo una prueba desde una aplicación WPF funciona correctamente, desde una aplicación de consola también.
El problema es que necesito realizar una llamada a un módulo desde un método de un servicio WCF, si lo tengo contra IIS express obtengo la respuesta y funciona correctamente.
Pero si lo pongo contra el IIS local me da el siguiente error:

```
*Cannot load erx.dll
Server stack trace: 
   en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
   en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   en System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   en System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   en System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   en IService1.GetData(String value)
   en Service1Client.GetData(String value)*
```

Con IIS local, he conseguido que funcione de la siguiente manera:

- Agregar un proyecto de consola a la solución wcf, que consuma el wrapper y realice la llamada. Devuelve un código de salida para manejar la respueta.
- En el método del servicio, llamar a la consola mediante un process en modo silencioso.

He probado a copiar las librerías en:

- El directorio bin.
- Directorio de proyecto.
- C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv.

También he revisado:

- Los usuarios del proceso de ejecución.
- He puesto el usuario del proceso de ejecución del iis express (donde funciona) al proceso de ejecución del iis local.
- Permisos (sobre las librerías e iis)

Pero nada de esto ha funcionado.

No consigo saber por qué no me funciona desde un método de un servicio WCF contra iis, que es justo donde necesito que funcione.

Comment: Tenes bien configurado el IIS local con sus pool, carpeta, puertos?

Comment: Sí, si comentas en el método el código que consume el wrapper del entirex la llamada funciona correctamente.

Comment: Podes colocar el codigo? asi entiendo que metodo estas llamando y falla. Por otro lado. si vos pones http://localhost/service1.svc levanta? o la direccion que corresponda a llamar al metodo. Todo esto simplemente abriendo google chrome o IExplorer

Comment: Sí Ramiro, lo hago y lo publico. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente esté relacionado con que IIS copia las .DLLs del proyecto a una carpeta temporal llamada "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0\Temporary ASP.NET Files[Proyecto]". (Esto lo puedes ver si abres la ventana de 'modules' desde la pestaña Debug/Windwos y buscas una .dll de tu proyecto, podrás ver su ruta real en la carpeta temporal)

Es decir, que si tu directorio virtual apunta a una carpeta, IIS no está ejecutando tu aplicación desde esa carpeta sino desde la carpeta temporal. Lo que ocurre es que solamente copia 'managed DLLs' por lo que tus librerías 'no managed' probablemente no los encuentre.

Por ejemplo, prueba eliminar de la carpeta bin de tu proyecto WPF las librerías  'not managed' a ver si te da el mismo error.

Comment: Hola Rauland Yo también pienso que puedo trararse de un problema de este tipo. Realicé la siguiente prueba: Añadí las librerías no administradas como elemento al proyecto y puse copiar siempre en en el directorio de salida, pero no funcionó. Voy a copiarlas manualmente a ver que pasa y te digo. Gracias.

Comment: Prueba copiarlos, como prueba, a la carpeta c:/windows a ver si funciona. Pero probablemente lo mejor sea copiarlos a una ruta de de entorno. (Environment Variables/Path)

Comment: Otra cosa a tener en cuenta, probablemente, el proceso WPF o los procesos donde te funcione sean 32bits, prueba forzar que se ejecute WPF en 64bits y comprueba si te da el mismo error. Si es así, también estará relacionado el problema con el tipo de proceso y en IIS habría que habilitar que el proceso sea 32 bits, se hace habilitando en el application pool, 'Enable 32 bit applications'.

Comment: Desde task manager (administrador de tareas) puedes ver facilmente si el proceso es de 32/64 bits.